# HPCC - ECL: Module "name" does not EXPORT an attribute main()

Tags: hpcc, hpcc-ecl

I have been explaining to others what "Module name does not EXPORT an attribute main()" error means and how to fix it.
Every time I answer this question I say it's because MODULE is a container that holds definitions or actions and the correct way is importing it to your code and referencing the EXPORTed values.
Exp:
IMPORT ModName;
ModName.SomeValue;

I was wondering if there is a better way to explain why modules aren't executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your answer is entirely correct.
As I say every time I teach an Intro ECL class, "Do NOT get into the BAD habit of just hitting Submit on every definition you add, because it doesn't always work! ALWAYS use a separate BWR (Builder Window Runnable) file to create a test case for that definition, whether just hitting Submit works or not!"